# undefined method `source_tag_names' for #<Cucumber::Ast::Scenario (no method error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I am using Rails 3.1.3 and getting the following error when executing a cuke:

```
undefined method `source_tag_names' for #<Cucumber::Ast::Scenario:0x00000104a7e770>(NoMethodError)
../gems/capybara-1.1.2/lib/capybara/cucumber.rb:18:in `Before'
```

Here is my Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '3.1.3'
group :test, :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.7.0'
  gem 'cucumber', '~> 1.1.3'
  gem 'capybara', '~> 1.1.2'
  gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.5.0'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', '~> 1.2.1'
  gem "database_cleaner"
end
```

I added specific versions after all else failed (getting latest).

Does anyone have an idea what's wrong with my setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cucumber 1.1.5 introduced a backwards-incompatible change that capybara was depending on:

- https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/pull/644
- https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/issues/227

Make sure you're using the latest version of cucumber, and you should be good!

Comment: Reportedly, Cucumber 1.1.6 will be out tomorrow with a fix: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/issues/227.

Comment: For anybody late to the party, as of now you can point to cucumber-rails 1.1.8 and then run bundle update. Or just update if you aren't setting the version.

Comment: Thanks Daniel & yakiimo - all's green again :)